# Parameter names with ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, keyword-argument

I have defined a function like:

```
function call_api(url, callback, query = {}, body = {})
```

I expected a syntax where I can provide body and skip query:

```
call_api('/api/clients/new', function(x){console.log(x)}, body={1:2})
```

But I have to use this workaround:

```
call_api('/api/clients/new', function(x){console.log(x)}, {}, {1:2})
```

Even if I provide `body=`, it appears its appearing as the `query` parameter. I use Babel with Webpack. I tried the syntax in Chrome console and in Webpack source.

Is such a syntax supported by ES6? How does it work?

Comment: Great article on your options: http://www.2ality.com/2011/11/keyword-parameters.html

Comment: Default values != named arguments

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I recommend that you work around this with passing an object and using destructuring for objects:

```
function callApi({url, callback, query = {}, body = {}})
```

And then call it as:

```
callAPI({url: "/api/..", callback: (x => console.log(x)), body: {a:2}})
```

Which would give you syntax similar to the one you want.

Named arguments have been considered and rejected for JavaScript, unlike other languages like C# and Python which sport them. [Here is a recent discussion about it](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/named-paramters) from the language mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

As shown on [this site](http://es6-features.org/#DefaultParameterValues), the defaults are just for parameters that need a default value (like an options parameter), but not for 'skipping' parameters.

What you're trying to do is

```
// function definition
function hi(a,b,c,d)

// function call
hi(a,b,d)
```

ES6 is still going to think that your 'd', is the defined c, regardless of your default value.
So no, ES6 does not have such syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify which parameter you assign to in your call.

`call_api('/api/clients/new', function(x){console.log(x)}, body={1:2})`

Is equivalent to setting a variable named body outside of the function and then passing its value in the query parameter's spot.

You could use destructuring to achieve what you want though.

`function call_api(url, callback, {query = {}, body = {}} = {})`

Then in your call you would do this

`call_api('/api/clients/new', function(x){console.log(x)}, {body:{1:2}})`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work if you call your function without a third argument at all ... however ... `function call_api(url, callback, {query={}, body={}}={})` does

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that. That's what I get typing code quickly into a textbox. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that the default parameter value is only used when the parameter is undefined, the only way to "skip" a parameter and fall back to the default would be to send `undefined` in it's place:

```
call_api('/api/clients/new', function(x){console.log(x)}, undefined, {1:2})
```

*Example: [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=function%20call_api(url%2C%20callback%2C%20query%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20body%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%7B%0A%20%20console.log('url%3A'%2C%20url)%3B%0A%20%20console.log('callback%3A'%2C%20callback)%3B%0A%20%20console.log('query%3A'%2C%20query)%3B%0A%20%20console.log('body%3A'%2C%20body)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Acall_api('%2Fapi%2Fclients%2Fnew'%2C%20function(x)%7Bconsole.log(x)%7D%2C%20undefined%2C%20%7B1%3A2%7D))*

The value of `query` within the function will be `{}` (or whatever you set default to) in this case.

This would be somewhat similar to [what Visual Basic does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f25e2b6b.aspx) when you want to use the default parameter value by passing an empty value. (e.g. `sub name(argument 1, , , argument 4)`)

Otherwise, if you wanted support for named parameters, the best compromise would be the answer supplied by @Benjamin Gruenbaum.

---

*Update:* You might find [this article provides an option using the `arguments` keyword](http://www.markhansen.co.nz/javascript-optional-parameters/), or better yet, you could [iterate over the ES6 `...rest` parameters collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to simulate an [overloaded function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) in Javascript.