# Why does the order class instantiation affect whether a class type is ready to use in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

If `new A()` and `new B()` are both idempotent, wouldn't you always expect `new A(); new B();` to succeed if `new B(); new A();` succeeds?

The following produces a confusing error (confusing because I'm not trying to reference `host`, but supply it as a parameter to B, which it has as a constructor parameter):

```
#app.js
const DEFAULT_HOST = "localhost";

class B {
    constructor(host = null) { console.log(`HOST: ${host}`); }
}

class A {
    constructor() { new B(host = DEFAULT_HOST) }
}

console.log(new A());
console.log(new B(host=123));
```

```
% npm app.js
    constructor() { new B(host = DEFAULT_HOST) }
                               ^

ReferenceError: host is not defined
    at new A (/home/sir/app.js:8:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sir/app.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

But switch the last two, lines, and there is no exception. Huh?!

```
console.log(new B(host=123));
console.log(new A());
```

The following works fine, so I have to assume it's some magic to do with classes:

```
const DEFAULT_HOST = "localhost";

function b(host = null) { console.log(`HOST: ${host}`); }

function a() { b(host = DEFAULT_HOST) }

console.log(a());
console.log(b(host=123));
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `host = DEFAULT_HOST` and `host=123` instead of just `DEFAULT_HOST` and `123` to pass in the values?

Comment: You are doing an assignment of 123 to the variable host which doesn't exist. But host is undefined right? It should just be 

`new B(123)` same here: `b(host=123)` should be `b(123)`

Comment: the basic problem is that you're imagining JS has "keyword arguments", when it doesn't. `new B(host=123)` tries to set a variable `host` to the value 123, then calls B's constructor with that value - but it crashes because there is no such variable. You need to just do `new B(123)`. I'm really not sure why your other versions are working, although I suspect it's to do with weird built-in browser stuff concerning a global variable called `host` perhaps. (But I haven't dug into it.)

Comment: So .. are the rules for keyword arguments different from constructor parameters, vs functions?

Comment: `b(host = null)` is ok because its a default value of a function parameter.

Comment: Why isn't B(host=null) ok because its a default value for a constructor function?

Comment: Your problem is here... `console.log(new B(host=123));` and here `new B(host = DEFAULT_HOST)`

It trying to assign 123 to host. But host is undefined in that context.

Comment: *groan* So ... `function f(a=1, b=2){return a;}
console.log(f(b=3)); ` ... prints 3. Wow. This language is just full of footguns.

Comment: And its not obvious why the above even succeeds, while the following fails.
function f(a=1, b=2){return a;}  console.log(b);
What's the purpose of this syntax allowing the assignment operator in parameter declarations?

Comment: Assignments return the assigned value. So `b=3` assigns `3` to `b` and evaluates to `3`. `f(b=3)` is equivalent to `b=3; f(3);`.

Comment: b=3 assigns 3 to b. ... except that you can't then reference b, because b is not a variable.

Comment: `b=3` is equivalent to `var b=3` (though I don't think you can explicitly use `var` in a function call). `var` is implied if you don't use `var`, `let`, `const`. If the variable didn't exist previously, it's created.

Comment: In the browser, `function f(a=1, b=2){console.log(a,b)}; f(b=3); console.log(b);` prints two lines: `3 2` and `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Order of operations

When you call a function (a class method, a class constructor, an anonymous function) the javascript is evaluated before the value is passed. JavaScript evaluates the assignment then passes the result of the assignment to the function.

```js
'use strict'
const DEFAULT_HOST = 'localhost';
let foo;
class B {
  constructor(host) {
    console.log(`B created with "${host}"`);
  }
}

new B(foo = DEFAULT_HOST);
```

In this case js tries to assign `DEFAULT_HOST` to a variable named `host`. But what is host? `host` is undefined. So it throws an error.

```js
'use strict';
const DEFAULT_HOST = 'localhost';
class B {
  constructor(foo) {
    console.log(`B created with "${foo}"`);
  }
}

// Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
new B(foo = DEFAULT_HOST);
```

##### Default parameters

The default parameter value is assigned to a parameter if it's not passed to the function.

```js
'use strict';
const DEFAULT_HOST = "localhost";
class Foo {
  constructor(host = DEFAULT_HOST) {
    // ...start server
    console.log(`Server running on "${host}"`)
  }
}

var foo = new Foo(); // Server running on "localhost"
var foo = new Foo('127.0.0.1'); // Server running on "127.0.0.1"


function saveHost(host = DEFAULT_HOST) {
    // ...do save stuff
    console.log(`${host} saved to disk`)
}
saveHost() // localhost saved to disk
saveHost('127.0.0.1') // 127.0.0.1 saved to disk
```

##### Named parameters

The closest thing JavaScript has to named parameters is destructuring. Where we pass in an object and it is destructured...

```js
function foo({x: someX, y: someY}) {
    console.log(`SomeX is ${someX}. SomeY is ${someY}`);
}
foo({x: 5, y: 6})
```

See also: [Parameter names with ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353186/parameter-names-with-es6)

##### Try this

If you want to fix the code in your comment. Try the following.

```js
const DEFAULT_HOST = "localhost";

class B {
  constructor(host = null) {
    console.log(`HOST: ${host}`);
  }
}

class A {
  constructor() {
    new B(DEFAULT_HOST);
  }
}

new A(); // HOST: localhost
new B(123); // HOST: 123
new B(); // HOST: null
```

Comment: Thank you. That is very clear. But also, good grief - the language supports variable declarations ... but they're sometimes optional... 

Answer (score 4):

You have your notation mixed up, for one. Parameters to JS functions do not have names - to pass a value, just pass the value, regardless of the name the function's internals uses for it. This:

```
console.log(new B(host=123));
```

should be

```
console.log(new B(123));
```

for `B`'s constructor to see the argument `123` and put it into the `host` identifier.

As for why the error is thrown - you cannot retrieve a value from an identifiers that do not exist, but (in sloppy mode) you can assign a value to an identifier that doesn't exist, resulting in the property being put onto the global object. For example:

```js
// OK
bar = '123';

// forbidden
console.log(foo);
```

(Always declare variables before using them, and consider always using strict mode.)

This throws an error in strict mode:

```
new B(host = DEFAULT_HOST)
```

because it's equivalent to: (*first* resolving the expression in the argument list):

```
const result = (host = DEFAULT_HOST);
new B(result);
```

And constructors run in strict mode, which forbids assigning to nonexistent identifiers:

```js
class B {
  constructor() {
    function foo() {
      console.log(this);
    }
    foo();
  }
}
new B();
```

But the code outside of a class *may not be strict mode* - such as in your code. In sloppy mode, assigning to a nonexistent identifier is permitted (just very strange to do).

```js
// IN SLOPPY MODE, so the following is permitted (but strange):
bar = 'bar';



class B {
  constructor() {
    // IN STRICT MODE, so the following is forbidden:
    foo = 'foo';
  }
}
new B();
```

Your code with `new B(host = DEFAULT_HOST)` fails in strict mode (inside the constructor) because the `host` identifier doesn't exist, and doesn't throw in sloppy mode (outside the constructor).

Comment: 'assigning to a nonexistent identifier is permitted'  (facepalm).

Comment: The moral. Always 'use strict'. Thanks